# nginx-gridfs connection failure

Tags: mongodb, nginx

I have nginx version 1.0.6 with nginx-gridfs module v0.8 installed.  I have a testing account on mongohq as mongodb://:@staff.mongohq.com:20127/Test

I set the location attribute in my conf as

```
location /gridfs/ {
            gridfs Test field=_id
                type=objectid
                user=<user>
                pass=<password>;
        mongo staff.mongohq.com:20127;
 }
```

when i start nginx i got the following exception and no worker process can start.

Mongo Exception: Connection Failure.

can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Your nginx conf looks good. I think the problem is that whatever server is running this nginx server really doesn't have access to the mongo server at `staff.mongohq.com:20127` with that `<user>` and `<password>`. I'd recommend double checking those settings.

Comment: i tried to do mongo staff.mongohq.com:20127/Test -u <user> -p <password> i was able to connect with mongo client

Answer (score 0):

There is no wrong with the configuration. I face the same issue. The solution that I found, I change the hostname into IP and the problem gone :). Try:

```
> nslookup staff.mongohq.com
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
staff.mongohq.com   canonical name = ec2-50-17-135-240.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
Name:    ec2-50-17-135-240.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Address: 50.17.135.240
```

Now, we have IP of `staff.mongohq.com` then change the line:

`mongo staff.mongohq.com:20127;`

to

`mongo 50.17.135.240:20127;`

Not sure where the problem is, is it on `nginx-gridfs` or `mongo-c-driver` but I am glad now it's working now :D